# Select="selected" after POST?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, post

I just want to Keep the listbox item selected after it has send the code to Iframe but I really don't know what to do ... here's my code ^^

```html
<?PHP
if(isset($_POST['options'])){
$epinum = $_POST['options'];
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<SELECT class='listofepisodes' NAME='options' onchange='this.form.submit()' size='1200'>
<?PHP
$options=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
while($option=mysql_fetch_array($options)) {
$image=$option['link'];
$number=$option['number'];
?>
<option value="<?PHP echo $image; ?>">Option <?PHP echo $number; ?></option>
<?PHP } ?>
</SELECT>
</form>
<iframe name="iframe" src="<?PHP echo $epinum; ?>" height="388" width="640" frameborder="1" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compare the $_POST['options'] with $image and echo 'selected' to option tag as follows:

```
<?PHP
if(isset($_POST['options'])){
$epinum = $_POST['options'];
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<SELECT class='listofepisodes' NAME='options' onchange='this.form.submit()'     size='1200'>
<?PHP
$options=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
while($option=mysql_fetch_array($options)) {
$image=$option['link'];
$number=$option['number'];
?>
<option value="<?PHP echo $image; ?>" <?php if(isset($_POST['options']) && $_POST['options']==$image) echo 'selected'; ?>>Option <?PHP echo $number; ?></option>
<?PHP } ?>
</SELECT>
</form>
<iframe name="iframe" src="<?PHP echo $epinum; ?>" height="388" width="640" frameborder="1" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: mm seems like it works but the first option gives this 
Notice:  Undefined index: options in ********/***.php
&gt;Option 1

Comment: Rest of options seem to be fine just the first option gives this error ... any idea?

Comment: I forgot to add isset($_POST['options']). Fixed

Comment: I was actually thinking the same thing and when I fixed it u corrected it but ThankYou very much I couldn't come up with such ... thanks ^^